# Connectivity between Azure SQL MI and On-prme SQL

Tags: sql, azure, networking, azure-sql-database

**Scenario ::** we want to enable communication between on-premise SQL Server and Azure SQL MI which should be super secure and fast.

After researching a lot, we have found two solutions::

1. Public endpoint
2. Site to Site (VPN)

**Question ::** now we are confused about which way we should go-ahead and Why?

**Requirement ::** have connectivity between on-prem SQL server and Azure MI so that we can push data to Azure SQL MI via a custom-built application.

Answer (score 0):

The VPN option is difficult to configure if you are not a network expert. You need to have good knowledge of VNet, ExpressRoute and VPN P2S and understand new notions of Azure networking. The VPN option does not provide separation of duties. The VPN option has also some known issues in terms of throughput so the endpoint gives you better performance.

The public endpoint option is easier to configure and allows for separation of duties. Your database administrator will enable the endpoint and the network administrator will make accesible the endpoint by opening port 3342 and provide a UDR route. Your DBA will need RBAC permissions on scope Microsoft.Sql/managedInstances/* while your administrator will need permissions on Microsoft.Network/*.